# How to show data between a two times using grep command

Tags: bash, awk, grep

I am trying to see all entries entered between 15:00 to 15:45 on Nov 9 using following command:

```
grep -E "Nov  9 15:00|Nov  9 15:45" /mac1/user1log
```

But this does not show from 15:00 to 15:45, but only 15:00 and 15:45

I know `awk` is better, but I need to run this from a bash script and `awk` can't run from bash script!

Comment: What makes you think `awk` can't run from a bash script?

Comment: Is the file sorted by date or just random lines? Can you give example input and desired output?

Comment: @RJHunter because I tried to run it from bash script, but it did not run and I am not very familiar with `awk`.

Comment: this file entries look like `month  day  time(hour):minutes"`. Output just need to show between desired time.

Comment: `awk` is a long time standard in bash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to achieve what you're trying to do with grep (more specifically, the extended-regexp option) you need to provide a regular expression. Regular expressions are somewhat limited but I came up with a simple answer for this specific scenario.

```
bash>grep -E "Nov  9 15:[0123][0-9]|Nov  9 15:[4][0-5]" testFile
```

The contents of testFile are the following:

```
Nov  9 15:02
Nov  9 15:01
Nov  9 15:09
Nov  9 15:39
Nov  9 15:49
Nov  9 15:59
```

But this should work fine for the scenario you presented.

```
bash>grep -E "Nov  9 15:[0123][0-9]|Nov  9 15:[4][0-5]" testFile
Nov  9 15:02
Nov  9 15:01
Nov  9 15:09
Nov  9 15:39
```

The first portion of the expression matches anything from Nov 9 15:00 to 15:39 and the second portion matches anything from Nov 9 15:40 to 15:45.

Edit: The syntax portion of it is just standard, regular expression numeric ranges. [0123][0-9] Means it will match anything containing 0, 1, 2 or 3 followed by any other digit from 0-9 (01, 02, 03, 39, etc.) while [4][0-5] matches 4, followed by any digit ranging from 0 to 5.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This works, can you please explain the syntax, so I know how it is working?

Comment: I have edited the answer to include a quick explanation. May I recommend reading up on http://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html ?

Comment: can be simplified to `grep -E 'Nov  9 15:([0-3][0-9]|[4][0-5])'`